# Frame property on ToolWindowPane is null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vs-extensibility

I'm writing a visual studio package. And here I want to open Tool Window. After initialization of tool window **ToolWindowPane window = new MyToolWindow();**, Frame property is null.

Don't know why.

P.S. MyToolWindow is a class inhereted from ToolWindowPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VS Package wizard of VS until VS 2013 and the Add New Item > Toolwindow mechanism of VS 2015 show how to create a toolwindow, but anyway see: [HOWTO: Create a toolwindow with a ToolWindowPane class in a Visual Studio package](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2015/MZ2015004.aspx)